# Sequelize many-to-many association - Method not found

Tags: javascript, node.js, orm, sails.js, sequelize.js

I have two n:m sequelize models as shown below

```
// Organization Model

module.exports = {

    attributes: {
        id: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true
        },
        name: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
            required: true
        },
    },
    associations: function() {

        Organization.belongsToMany(Contact, {
            through : OrganizationContact,
            foreignKey: {
                name: 'organizationId',
                allowNull: false
            }
        });

    }
};

// OrganizationContact Model

module.exports = {

    attributes: {
        id: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true
        }
    }
}



// Contact Model

module.exports = {

    attributes: {
        id: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true
        },
        firstname: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
            required: true
        },
        lastname: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
            required: false
        },
    },
    associations: function() {

        Contact.belongsToMany(Organization, {
            through : OrganizationContact,
            foreignKey: {
                name: 'contactId',
                allowNull: false
            }
        });

    }
};
```

I am trying to insert a contact and attach it to an existing organization. My data looks like

```
{
    "firstname" : "Mathew",
    "lastname" : "Brown",
    "organizationId" : 1 // Add the contact to an existing organization. I am missing something here.
}
```

**Note : There can be multiple contacts attached to multiple organizations. An organization is created before a contact.**

Based on [this](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/1.7.0/docs/associations/#many-to-many-associations) documentation, after saving the contact when I tried

```
Organization.addContact(contact);
```

I get an exception saying

```
Organization.addContact is not a function
```

Comment: How did you name the models (first parameter of `sequelize.define` method)?

Comment: I'm using sails-sequelize-hook.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `addContact` method should be called on instance of `Organization` rather than on the model itself, just as you do in the example code.

```
Organization.create(organizationData).then(organization => {
    organization.addContact(contact).then(() => {
        // contact was added to previously created organization
    });
});
```

You do not need the `organizationId` attribute in your contact create data. If you want to add new contact to the organization with `id: 1`, then you first need to return the organization instance and then perform the `addContact` method

```
Organization.findByPrimary(1).then(organization => {
    organization.addContact(contact).then(() => {
         // contact was added to organization with id = 1
    });
});
```